# List of default managed properties in SharePoint search

Tags: sharepoint

I would like to what are the default managed properties available with default installation of a SharePoint. Also would like to know what is the default crawling property name maped to a managed property "ModifiedBy".

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, we've changed our Managed Properties so I'm not sure about the complete list of default properties. Here is what I have listed for ModifiedBy:

```
ModifiedBy
    ows_ModifiedBy
    ows_Modified_x0020_By
    8
    ows_Last_x0020_Modified
```

You can view the current Managed Properties in Central Admin.

1. Go to Central Admin
2. Click on your SSP name in the left hand nav
3. Click Search Administration
4. Click Metadata Properties

Or, if you are interested, you can write a little console application to print all of the properties. ([reference here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb428648.aspx))

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("output.txt", false))
{
    ServerContext serverContext = ServerContext.GetContext("Your_SSP_Name");
    SearchContext searchContext = SearchContext.GetContext(serverContext);
    Schema schema = new Schema(searchContext);
    foreach (ManagedProperty prop in schema.AllManagedProperties)
    {
        sw.WriteLine(prop.Name);
        foreach (Mapping mapping in prop.GetMappings())
        {
            sw.WriteLine(string.Format("\t{0}", mapping.CrawledPropertyName));
        }
    }
}
```